# C# Game Development for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am interested at trying my skills at game development.  I am a fairly good C# developer.  But my current skill set is in application development (WPF, WCF and Entity Framework).

I am trying to figure out how to make a graphical game for Windows Phone 8.  But all the examples I see (for games) are using C++.

8+ years ago I was a C++ Game Developer, but I have forgotten most of those skills (I doubt they would be useful now days anyway).

I am not looking for 3D rendering.  Just a nice 2D (Tower Defense) game.

I would rather code in C# if possible. **Can game development be done using C#?**

If so, a pointer on where to start would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I have been able to find out:

There is a library called SharpDX that allows you to call DirectX from C#.  It seems fairly good.

But, the Windows Phone makers did not include support for Direct2D.  So unless you are planning to make a fully 3D app, you are out of luck (and that is a lot of work let me tell you!).

So, if you just wanted to make a nice 2D app, these are your choices:

1. Write your game using Xaml and C# (Performance Issues?)
2. Write your game using C#, SharpDX and 3d (but only draw on one plain) (A lot of work for 2d).
3. Use the DirectX Took Kit found on codeplex.  It allows you to use the dying XNA framework's API for development (This is a C++ option).

Comment: option 2) is now made easier by using monogame

Comment: I ended up choosing the option of writing only the rendering code in Windows Runtime component (C++) and having the game logic written in C# doing most the work and controlling the Renderer with an API you publish from the Runtime component, only downside to this approach I've found is you have to structure your code to minimize the number of API calls.

Answer (score 3):

Support for C++ has been added in Windows Phone 8. On Windows Phone 7, apps could only be developed using Silverlight or XNA. It didn't prevent developers to publish thousands of games, including mainstream titles like Plants vs Zombies or Angry Birds. Therefore, I believe it's safe to conclude that game development is indeed possible in C#.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us the Windows 8 sdk is now available. According to their samples, most are actually done using C#. You can also find some XNA game examples there too.

Comment: Maybe I need to look harder.  I filtered by C# and found only "Applications" not games.  (I did only check the top 10 pages or so.)

Comment: try this one: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Xna-Ball-Bouncing-Game-77a44f5d

Comment: Hmmm, this confuses me.  This MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) says: "You can’t create new XNA Framework apps that target Windows Phone OS 8.0."

Comment: @Vaccano - What is the different between an Application and Game exactly?  Both use the exact same SDK.  Windows Phone 8 support Direct X I would look toward your C++ experience for assistance with that.

Comment: @MikeB - That example was posted on May 18th.  Well before the Windows Phone 8 SDK was released (right?).  Are you sure it is for Windows Phone 8?

Comment: No, I doubt it was for Windows 8, but it does shoe that you can develop games using C# on the phone

Comment: @Ramhound - A game does not (normally) use standard UI controls (Textbox, Button, Label etc).  It has custom drawn items called sprites (at least they were called that 9 years ago).  How you draw/animate those is what I consider "Game" programming.  (And as I stated in my question, I know that C++ has many examples for doing this.  But I would like to know if it can be done with C#.)