# Setup Artemis + XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, windows-phone-8, xna

I am trying to set a coding environment for Windows Phone.
At first I was using the free version of Visual C# 2010, but compiling failed for the Artemis DLLs - Unsupported unit-testing modules...
So I downloaded Visual Studio 2012 - Compiling worked, but not for everything! The Xbox and Phone DLLs were not compiled.
The error message sent me to Visual Studio 2013 compatibility page.
...
I downloaded VS2013 - Same issue.

I want an environment for XNA + Artemis (Entity-based programming) for C# (PC and Windows Phone)

Can anyone please give me directions?

Is there a way to get a Windows Phone 8 emulator working on a non-Win 8 Pro environment? I have Win8 and I don't want to pirate a windows just so I could start an emulator for development. (I have a real DEV ID and SDK approval)

Also, I do not plan on coding with the VS2013/2012 (I already removed 2012, will do the same with 2013 if it is not needed for the set up) as I said, I wanted to compile the libraries (and couldn't with VisualC#!)

Comment: What I *do* know that works with both VS2010/VS2012 Express is Monogame.  Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was stated by Moo-Juice - "What I do know that works with both VS2010/VS2012 Express is Monogame. Check it out." 
This is not the answer I was looking for, but it's something I did not know of.
Thanks Moo-Juice

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, XNA is not anymore supported in the newest versions of Visual Studio (then 2012 and 2013).

Indeed, to create a little game some time ago, I used Visual Studio 2010, that was the last supported version for those libraries.

I don't know exactly how to create games in Windows Phone 8, without using XNA, but there's a library named [SharpDX](http://www.sharpdx.org/) that could be useful for you. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457580/c-sharp-game-development-for-windows-phone-8).

Comment: Thank you, I will go over it.
I know XNA is not supported in VS2012, but you need VS2012 for the Windows Phone 8 development. Kind of stupid from their part.

Comment: @AdamCohen You're welcome. Yes, I know that you need VS2012 to develop apps for Windows Phone 8. I think they ended the support for XNA, not only because maybe the technology had to be rewritten for the new mobile OS, but also to let the developers focus on new 'methods' to develop games, using DirectX, C++ and HTML/Javascript. Anyway I agree with you.